# .NET: DateTime settings are different on one machine

Tags: .net, datetime, locale, culture, cultureinfo

I have two applications (web site and desktop application) launched on the one machine, both uses the following to serialize DateTime object value:

```
string strDateTileFullFormat = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    .GetConsoleFallbackUICulture().DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern;

string SummarySupporyUntil = string.Concat("until ",
     TestLicenseExpiryDate.ToString(strDateTileFullFormat));
```

One application create:
           "Saturday, December 31, 2011 12:00:00 AM",
another:
       "December 31, 2011 12:00:00 AM"

Difference is that one uses "Canada" country setting, another - "USA".

The problem is that I need these date to be similar (actually, I don't know which kind is correct, perhaps the 1st one).

I looked web/app.config files but don't see anything related to locale settings. Also, I don't have manual changes for CurrentCulture...

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Does the serialization format itself have any standard format for datetime (as is the case with XML for instance)? If so, it could be a good idea to settle for that format. If not, consider using some other standard instead of a local format, such as [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have decided which culture suits you best, you can use System.DateTime's powerful formatting features as stated in the doc: [DateTime.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx) with a fixed culture:

For example with en-US culture (1033):

```
string SummarySupporyUntil = string.Concat("until ",
     TestLicenseExpiryDate.ToString(strDateTileFullFormat, new Culture(1033)));
```

will give the same result on every machine it will be ran.